# jQuery does 2 loads... and returns 500 error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

For some reason my jQuery AJAX request submits the first POST successfully, but then it causes a second GET which does not submit the post data, causing a Index Undefined error. When viewing the logs with Firebug, I see it does the first POST successfully posting the data I want to submit, but then it does a second GET request pulling the entire "SecondPage.php" file without posting any data, overriding the DIV it was set to display in.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).on('change', '.SubmitRadioButton', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'SecondPage.php',
        cache: false,
        data: $(this.form).serialize(),
        success: function(html) { 
            window.alert('Successfully submitted AJAX request!');
            $("#DIVinFirstPage").load("SecondPage.php");
        }

    });
    return false;
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also - I have noticed that on this second PHP page I have to make a reference to my "Header.php" file that performs all the functions. Why is it that with this ajax request, it doesn't inherit all the rules from the page as a PHP include("File.php") does? Is there any way around this so I don't have to re-initialize and re-download all the PHP and JavaScript files? I tried include_once("File.php") in the PHP and that didn't correct it either.

Comment: Can you show us the error log/network? The code you provided does not show any GET request but it may be the form itself that is submitting it. And also to address your second problem -- PHP and JavaScript are different things. You cannot use PHP functions in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery load is the same thing as doing a $.get request. Is only a wrapper.

[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

So you are basically doing a post request with some data on this part of the code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'SecondPage.php',
    cache: false,
    data: $(this.form).serialize(),
    success: function(html) { 
        window.alert('Successfully submitted AJAX request!');
```

And then inside the success making a get request to the same page on this line.

```
        $("#DIVinFirstPage").load("SecondPage.php");
```

Then the page SecondPage.php is giving you an Index Undefined Error because SecondPage.php is expecting POST data which is not being sent in the .load call.

Since the Index Undefined is a php error, that sends the 500 error code to the browser.

So you need to either check if the variables are set using isset on SecondPage.php or make the load call another page that is not expecting any data.

Another alternative would be to have the script that handles the POST on a separate php file and then do the .load to the second page of your form.

Comment: Thanks! That explains why it didn't work as expected. Toby's solution answered it, but this explained it!

Answer (score 0):

In the success callback of the first POST request, you perform a JQuery load(). According to documentation http://api.jquery.com/load/, "It is roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success)".

You see your success callback function has a parameter named "html". That is the response served to your from SecondPage.php after the POST request. I imagine that contains the content you want to populate your div with.

Perhaps try:

```
success: function(html) { 
    window.alert('Successfully submitted AJAX request!');
    $("#DIVinFirstPage").html(html);
}
```